# Capturing end of string in C / Checking if string is an integer

Tags: c, string

I have funny piece of code in C:

```
int is_digit( char c){
    return ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) ? 1 : 0;
}

int is_number( char * s ){
    while( *s++ ){
        printf("%d", is_digit(*s));
        if( !is_digit(*s) ) return 0;           
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It gives output like this: `1110` for `is_number("8888");`

I compile it with `gcc -Wall -W` - no warnings and no errors

But it's incorrect( not checking first character ), so I wanted to do:

```
int is_number( char * s ){
    while( *s ){
        printf("%d", is_digit(*s));
        if( !is_digit(*s) ) return 0;
        s++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Same compiling options, no warnings, loops goes forever.

**Why?**

EDIT:
OK it's working. Another function is causing error. Just wrong makefile didn't updated code.

Comment: It works fine here. You probably invoke `is_number` in an infinite loop.

Comment: nothing in the second code snippet explain an infinite loop.

Comment: Did you try to debug this with a debugger ?

Comment: @Marian It also doesn't printf in loop( but im shure it's in this loopo( added normal printf ). And the first one shows that there is a 0 at the end of string. I use it like that is_number( argv[1] ). Could it change something?

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `s`  in the `while` expression's test. Thus you're checking the "next" character all the time.

The second version looks OK, although I would write it using a `for` since that is clearer:

```
for(; *s != '\0'; ++s) {
 ...
}
```

Perhaps you've failed to compile the program properly.

You should add a newline to the `printf()`, since standard output is often line-buffered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's working. I messed up makefile.